# Possible to Prevent Users from Deleting Their Own Notes

Tags: notes

I have [enabled Notes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=notes_setup_enable.htm&type=5) from "Note Settings" and am using them with *Accounts*

I understand that [access to notes is controlled by access to the associated object/record](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=notes_del.htm&type=5), and sharing settings for the note.

However, I am assume **it's not possible to prevent them from deleting their own notes** after they are created correct? Or am I missing something, there are not "Note Specific" Permissions defined on the profiles?

Is this true?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One cannot independently permission (Content) Notes. To prevent deletion, I think you'll have to go to an Apex trigger to add an error on the `before delete` event.

A very quick example of how to do this would be:

```
trigger NoteTrigger on ContentDocument (before delete) {
    for (ContentDocument c : Trigger.new) {
        if (c.FileType == 'SNOTE') {
            c.addError('You cannot delete a Note');
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this will prevent *everyone*, including System Administrators, from deleting *all* Notes, so it's probably not what you want exactly but you can add business logic around such a mechanism.

In a real trigger, I would want, at minimum, to provide a Custom Setting or Custom Permission-based exclusion so that you could selectively permit the deletion of Notes.

Comment: Thanks @David Reed that was my first suggestion when discussing this with colleagues but again - as you stated it has its issues.